# How can I keep `jupyter run` from timing out?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

Starting an Python Jupyter kernel with

```sh
> ipython kernel
```

and then launching a script in a separate terminal using

```sh
> jupyter run script.py --existing
```

results in a timeout error after around 10 seconds:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mason/.local/bin/jupyter-run", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(RunApp.launch_instance())
  File "/home/mason/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 264, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mason/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/home/mason/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/runapp.py", line 107, in start
    reply = self.kernel_client.execute_interactive(code, timeout=OUTPUT_TIMEOUT)
  File "/home/mason/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/utils.py", line 26, in wrapped
    raise e
  File "/home/mason/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/utils.py", line 23, in wrapped
    return loop.run_until_complete(future)
  File "/home/mason/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nest_asyncio.py", line 81, in run_until_complete
    return f.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/futures.py", line 178, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py", line 280, in __step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "/home/mason/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/client.py", line 515, in _async_execute_interactive
    raise TimeoutError("Timeout waiting for output")
TimeoutError: Timeout waiting for output
```

How can I keep this from happening? I tried looking through the `jupyter_client` code and changing various IPyKernel configuration options but I haven't had any luck. (What I'm trying to do, ultimately, is use Jupyter/IPyKernel to quickly re-run Python scripts that depend on slow-to-initialize modules like PyTorch.)

For reference, the only Pip package I needed to install to get this behavior was `ipykernel`, and the content of `script.py` is

```py
from time import sleep

for _ in range(20):
    print('Still running')
    sleep(1)
```